# g++ compilation error "... is protected from within this context" while there's no error with clang

Tags: c++, inheritance, gcc, clang

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

class BaseClass {
 protected:
 static int x;
};

int BaseClass::x;

class DerivedA: public BaseClass {
 public:
     DerivedA() {
        x = 3;
     }
};    

class DerivedB: public BaseClass {
 public:
     DerivedB() {
        std::cout << DerivedA::x;
     }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
        DerivedB b;
}
```

Compiling with g++ (`g++ classtest.cpp`) I receive the following error:

> classtest.cpp: In constructor ‘DerivedB::DerivedB()’:
>   classtest.cpp:9:5: error: ‘int BaseClass::x’ is protected
>    int BaseClass::x;
>            ^
>   classtest.cpp:25:32: error: within this context
>            std::cout << DerivedA::x;

When I'm compiling with clang++ (`clang++ classtest.cpp`) there's no error.

Why is g++ returning the compilation error?

I use g++ version 5.1.0 and clang++ version 3.6.1

Comment: It also compiles in MVS2015

Comment: I'm more surprised that clang is **not** throwing an error... But I can confirm, it's not.

Comment: @DrewDormann Why? I'm surprised by the error: despite the `DerivedA::`, it's actually accessing a protected member of `BaseClass`, from a class that is derived from `BaseClass`.

Comment: I'm not positive, but doesn't it make sense that you should be declaring x inside one of the extended classes? I mean otherwise it's just a global and the protected class doesn't know that it has permissions.

Comment: @TheHumanWall: `x` is declared as a static member of `BaseClass`. It is, and must be, defined separately.

Comment: DerivedA is optimized out in the emitted IR.

Comment: FWIW, this did work in GCC 4.3, but GCC 4.4 started giving error messages for it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

GCC bug. [class.access.base]/p5:

> A member `m` is accessible at the point `R` when named in class `N` if
>
> - `m` as a member of `N` is public, or
> - `m` as a member of `N` is private, and `R` occurs in a member or friend of class `N`, or
> - `m` as a member of `N` is protected, and `R` occurs in a member or friend of class `N`, or in a member of a class `P` derived from `N`,
>     where `m` as a member of `P` is public, private, or protected, or
> - there exists a base class `B` of `N` that is accessible at `R`, and `m` is accessible at `R` when named in class `B`.

`N` is `DerivedA`, `m` is `x`, `R` is the constructor of `DerivedB`. There exists a base class `BaseClass` of `DerivedA` that is accessible at `R`, and `x` named in class `BaseClass` (i.e., `BaseClass::x`) is plainly accessible at `R`, so by the fourth bullet point, `DerivedA::x` is accessible at `R`.

Comment: Thats one helluva bug. Even though the bullet in question is not the most common, its is not obscure by any means.

Comment: Can't find this on gcc's bugzilla - want to submit?

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. 
Too bad we can't offer bounties for tasks, such as opening a bugreport :)

Comment: good **grief**. hopefully this explains the pile of incomprehensible errors i'm currently getting with 5.2 trying to implement some semi-trivial crtp. currently downloading 223 mb of debian testing updates, which `aptitude versions` implies now includes 5.3. fingers crossed this horror is resolved!

Comment: *exciting update**: yup, debian testing now has 5.3, which immediately solves this problem. (well, it at least lets my code compile; whether or not the binary does anything useful remains to be seen!)